# Extracting the Desired Result from the Data

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regexp-replace

I have been using below formula to extract the relevant values from the data.

```
IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"TRN*1*\*[^~\\]+"))
```

Here is the Data.

```
ENTRY DESCR:HCCLAIMPMTSEC:CCD TRACE#:04858562 TRN*1*6523251452*5865418282584~
ENTRY DESCR:HCCLAIMPMTSEC:CCD TRACE#:04526412 TRN*1*5685952452*158615*6526352 26\ TRN: 563569856
```

and the output comes like this.

```
TRN*1*6523251452*5865418282584
TRN*1*5685952452*158615*6526352 26
```

But i want to extract the output like this

```
6523251452
5685952452
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you can use regexreplace and match `.*TRN\*1*\*(\d+)\*.*` and replace with group 1 https://regex101.com/r/DSpKFL/1

Comment: Thank you your answer works well @The fourth bird

Comment: Its working thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```golang
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"TRN\*1\d*\*(\d+)"))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/py1wh9/2).

*Details*:

- `TRN\*1\*` - `TRN*1*` string
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (this value will be the return value of the whole REGEXEXTRACT function): one or more digits.

Comment: Thank you very much its working. sorry for being late i was off duty so could not reply timely.

Comment: I would request you to please check this sheet i have found 1 problem here [Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eq9y3WzBjGKInNNIdKJE3MYeIxb9GrhSM7wCvbkgwEI/edit?usp=sharing)
 @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @Mento I do not know what you expect me to say. If you need to get all alphanumeric chars, not just digits, use `\w+`, not `\d+`.